# Not able to access array passed as props from parent - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Getting started with React. I have two drop-downs in the child component WeatherOptionsView. I'm trying to set it's default value based on the prop array of previously selected values passed from Parent component WeatherContainerView. I also want to set it to the state as the value will change onChange of dropdown going forward.

The UI blows up when I do this. When I print the values of props, I see that the selectedCodes is null. Where am I going wrong with this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
console.log(this.props.isFailed);        //false
console.log(this.props.selectedValues);   //null
```

WeatherOptionsContainer.js

```
class WeatherOptionsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isFailed: true, isLoading: false, selectedValues: ['City1', 'City2']};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WeatherOptionsView
        isFailed={this.state.isFailed}
        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
        selectedValues={this.state.selectedValues}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

WeatherOptionsView.js

```
    class WeatherOptionsView extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { reasonState: false, selectedValues: this.props.selectedValues };
      }

      render() {
        const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

        return (
          <ContentContainer fill>
            <Spacer marginTop="none" marginBottom="large+1" marginLeft="none" marginRight="none" paddingTop="large+2" paddingBottom="none" paddingLeft="large+2" paddingRight="large+2">
              <Fieldset legend="City">
                <Grid>
                  <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column tiny={3}>
                        <SelectField selectId="State1" required placeholder="Select" label={["City:"]} error={["Error message"]} isInvalid={this.state.reasonState} defaultValue={this.props.selectedValues[0]}>
                          <Select.Option value="City1" display="City1" />
                          <Select.Option value="City2" display="City2" />
                        </SelectField>
                       </Grid.Column>
                 </Grid.Row>                  
                 <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column tiny={3}>
                       <SelectField selectId="State2" required placeholder="Select" label={["City:"]} error={["Error message"]} isInvalid={this.state.reasonState} defaultValue={this.props.selectedValues[1]}>
                          <Select.Option value="City1" display="City1" />
                          <Select.Option value="City2" display="City2" />
                        </SelectField>                   
                  </Grid.Column>
                 </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            )}
            />
          </ContentContainer>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to avoid copying prop values to state: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is, you are passing the prop selectedCodes and in the inner component you are using this.props.selectedValues. This should work.

```
  constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { reasonState: false, selectedValues: this.props.selectedCodes };
          }
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. I changed it, but it's still showing the value as null.

Comment: I have created a sandbox example with your minimal code and getting the correct prop value.
here is the link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-night-z9594